# How to modify the Create Prepayment action/button on Purchase Order?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've successfully modified the process when a AP Bill is created by the action Create AP Bill on the Purchase Order page, but i need to do the same when the user wants to create a Prepayment.

To modify the creation of the AP Bill from the Purchase Order I just created a delegate and the new InvoicePOOrder function. But since the Prepayment is a Popup of the Prepayment screen it seems like it doesn't works the same way. I've searched through the code for the correct method to no avail. The only portion I find is on the CodeRepository.xml file.

```
    public PXAction<POOrder> createPrepayment;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Prepayment Request", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select,
        MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = true)]
    [PXButton(OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Cancel)]
    public virtual void CreatePrepayment()
    {
        if (Base.Document.Current != null)
        {
            Base.Save.Press();
            var target = PXGraph.CreateInstance<APInvoiceEntry>();
            var prepaymentExt = target.GetExtension<APInvoiceEntryExt.Prepayments>();
            prepaymentExt.AddPOOrderProc(Base.Document.Current, true);

            throw new PXPopupRedirectException(target, "New Prepayment", true);
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to access it directly on my customization or do I need to modify the xml to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Ok, no answer from me besides: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).  You could have copy/pasted the XML (or parts of it) and not create an image......

Comment: My bad, just edited.

Comment: Did you have a look at their forum? (for example: https://community.acumatica.com/search?q=create%20payment&category=Discussion%20Forums%20%3E%20Develop%20Customizations ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Prepayment action is declared on `Prepayment` graph extension in `PX.Objects.PO.GraphExtensions.POOrderEntryExt` namespace.

You need to create a secondary graph extension, and override CreatePrepayment action there.

```
public class PrepaymentExt : PXGraphExtension<Prepayments, POOrderEntry> {}
```

If you need to do the same thing on the "Popup", what is actually an `APInvoiceEntry` graph in the background, you can extend that graph or it's `Prepayment` extension in the same way.

Comment: Your advice helped a lot! I ended up overriding not the action but the method AddPOOrderProc in the Prepayment extension of the APInvoice, since I needed to append some info to custom fields.